# How to add class to Rails select form helper when using as a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The documentation for Rails select form helper states ([see documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)):

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Which allows adding a class simple, like so:

```
<%= f.select :some_attr, MYOPTIONS, {}, {class: 'my-class'} %>
```

My question is, how do I add a class to it when using it as a block? Rails documentation states:

```
select(report, "campaign_ids") do
  available_campaigns.each do |c|
    content_tag(:option, c.name, value: c.id, data: { tags: c.tags.to_json })
  end
end
```

It doesn't work when I use it like so:

```
<%= f.select :some_attr, {}, {class: 'my-class'} do %>
  <% MYOPTIONS.each do |MYOPTION| do %>
    <%= content_tag :option, MYOPTION.label, value: MYOPTION.value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Nor does it work if I use:

```
f.select :some_attr, class: 'my-class' do
```

The class is not applied to the select tag in the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my own problem, although I don't fully understand the answer, so if someone else understands this better, I'd love to hear your answer.

To get it to work, I simply added an additional empty hash to the beginning, like so:

```
<%= f.select :some_attr, {}, {}, {class: 'my-class'} do %>
  <% MYOPTIONS.each do |MYOPTION| do %>
    <%= content_tag :option, MYOPTION.label, value: MYOPTION.value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The second hash is still `options` and the last is still `html_options`, so as an example, you can also add `include_blank` like so:

```
f.select :some_attr, {}, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'my-class'}
```

However, I don't know what the first hash is, nor what values can be passed there. I've looked at the Rails source, but I still have no clue. If you have insight into this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 5):

A couple oddities to be aware of:

In your example, you're using `f.select`, which you can find a reference for here:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Only the first parameters is required, the rest have defaults. However, to assign that HMTL class, you had to have a value for the fourth parameter, which necessitated having something for the second and third parameters as well.

What you ended up with is a valid solution:

```
<%= f.select :some_attr, {}, {}, {class: 'my-class'} do %>
  <% MYOPTIONS.each do |MYOPTION| do %>
    <%= content_tag :option, MYOPTION.label, value: MYOPTION.value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The block, when provided, takes precedence over the literal value (an empty hash in this case).

Surprisingly, if you were rendering this tag using `select_tag` instead of `f.select`, passing a block wouldn't be an option:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag